# Flashback occurs when compiling tensorflow into my Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-android

Flashback occurs when compiling tensorflow into my project. The original project worked fine at first, but when I compile tensorflow or link tensorflow C++ source files to my project, the original function in the app

[image]

flashes back. I found that when I ran to the next step, it should have continued(Execute test1 and test2), but it flashed back.OnlineService is the class imported by the external jar package
(I thought it was not compatible with the version at first, because the original project minSdkVersion:7 and targetSdkVersion:8, but I changed it to 15 and 22, the original project works normally, and the above situation still occurs), I don't know why this is happening.